# how to disable all webkit browser plugins?

Tags: python, webview, webkit

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I have [Pipelight](https://launchpad.net/pipelight) installed - this NPAPI browser plugin allows me to view Silverlight & new Flash based stuff in Firefox.

However this has an unfortunate side effect - all web-browsers that support NPAPI plugins such as WebKit also load this plugin.

Programatically, I would like to disable all browser plugins when I create the WebKit.WebView - thus to my question.  How do I do this?

---

Investigations:

I've looked at using WebKit2 - this does work probably because WebKit2 does not have NPAPI support.  However I cannot use this method because Rhythmbox by default has another native plugin which is WebKit i.e. I'm creating another Rhythmbox plugin.  When I attempt to load both a WebKit.WebView and WebKit2.WebView at the same time then the process hangs.

I've looked at using [WebKit.WebSettings](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit-3.0/classes/WebSettings.html#WebKit.WebSettings) and its [enable-plugins](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit-3.0/classes/WebSettings.html#WebKit.WebSettings.props.enable_plugins) property but it appears you cannot apply the new WebSettings instance until after the WebView has been created (thus the pipelight browser plugin is already loaded).

Again - I've tried to assign the new WebSettings instance via the constructor but no joy: `x = WebKit.WebView(settings=webkit_settings)`

When you have pipelight installed a simple test program (web.py) like this shows the issue:

```
from gi.repository import WebKit

webkit_settings = WebKit.WebSettings.new()
webkit_settings.props.enable_plugins=False
x = WebKit.WebView.new()
x.set_settings(webkit_settings)
```

Then running `python web.py` shows an example output of

```
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_0_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.0.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/foss/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] unrecognized configuration key 'diagnosticmode'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] using wine prefix directory /home/foss/.wine-pipelight.
```

I've posed this [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+question/260874) to the Pipelight developers and they have indicated that I need to disable plugins via the WebKit engine. As you can see - I thought WebKit2 was my solution but I cannot use this as stated above.

I've seen this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209844/suppress-plugin-loading-in-webkit) but I'm not really after disabling specific plugins - at least I dont think so - just want to disable all external plugins

I'm writing this using Python3 but I dont think the python version is the issue here since I've run the test program using both the python and python3 interpreter and the same results are seen.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked this by writing my own access() function which 
calls strstr(pathname, "/plugins/"); If this returns non-null
function sets errno to ENOENT and returns -1.

Otherwise my access() calls the original access() (system call wrapper)
from c library.

In c program such a function can just be implemented, for other programs
separate c module and LD_PRELOAD can be used...

like this:

```
static void * dlsym_next(const char * symbol)
{
    void * sym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, symbol);
    char * str = dlerror();

    if (str != null)
        exit(1);

    return sym;
}
#define set_next(name) *(void**)(&name##_next) = dlsym_next(#name)

int access(const char * pathname, int mode)
{
    static int (*access_next)(const char *, int) = NULL;
    if (! access_next)
        set_next(access);

    if (strstr(pathname, "/plugins/") != NULL) {
        errno = ENOENT;
        return -1;
    }
    return access_next(pathname, mode);
}
```